# res.json() is not setting content-type to application/json in express.js

Tags: express

**MY CODE**

```
const express =  require('express')
const app = express()
const {products} = require('./data.js')

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json(products)
    console.log(products);
})

app.listen(3000,() =>{
    console.log(`Server listening on Port 3000`);
})
```

**data.js**

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'albany sofa',
    image:
      'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/6ac7f7b55d505057317534722e5a9f03/9183491e/product-3.jpg',
    price: 39.95,
    desc: `I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian.`,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'entertainment center',
    image:
      'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/da5e17fd71f50578d525dd5f596e407e/d5e88ac8/product-2.jpg',
    price: 29.98,
    desc: `I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian.`,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'albany sectional',
    image:
      'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/05ecddf7ac8d581ecc3f7922415e7907/a4242abc/product-1.jpeg',
    price: 10.99,
    desc: `I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian.`,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'leather sofa',
    image:
      'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/3245c726ee77d73702ba8c3310639727/f000842b/product-5.jpg',
    price: 9.99,
    desc: `I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian.`,
  },
]
const people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, name: 'peter' },
  { id: 3, name: 'susan' },
  { id: 4, name: 'anna' },
  { id: 5, name: 'emma' },
]
module.exports = { products, people }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/skQtI.png)

The response header in the above image should have content-type: application/json but somehow i am not receiving any content-type

Although res.json() should set the content-type by deafult, it did not do so in my case and even after explicitly setting the content type as shown in my code above, the content-type was not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code unchanged **does** send a Content-Type header.

Running it with Node v18.16.0 and Express 4.18.2 and making a request shows:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:3000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1208
< ETag: W/"4b8-2tLfvRMolX6TrYvoofapRkqVr2A"
< Date: Sun, 16 Apr 2023 09:10:55 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"id":1,"name":"albany sofa","image": ........ etc.
```

When you change the line:

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

to:

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

**or** to the shorhand:

```js
res.type('text');
```

The content type header gets changed to:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

When you completely remove the header changing line:

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

The content-type header is still:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The only way I see for you to not see the correct header is:

1. you have some middleware that removes or changes the content-type header in your real application that you didn't include in your code example
2. you connect via some proxy that changes or removes the content-type header
3. you are not getting the response that you are expecting (other URL or port, or some caching takes place)
4. while making the request you don't read the headers correctly

If 1 and 2 are not true then make sure that the way you verify if the header is there actually shows you the headers, e.g. by making a request in the same way to a URL that is known to correctly return json content type header, like e.g. https://api.github.com/

Some examples:

- `curl http://localhost:3000/` doesn't show any headers but just body
- `curl -I http://localhost:3000/` shows headers only
- `curl -v http://localhost:3000/` shows you full request with headers, and full response with headers and body (most detailed and recommended)

Note that when you are making a request with a browser or some other caching user agent, you may get a reply with some other status than 200 OK, e.g. 304 Not Modified (and looking more closely at the screenshot that you linked seems that this might me the case - next time yu may want to include the most important data in your question instead of linking to screenshots so that it is easier to diagnose the problem and answer for other people) but it seems that the request headers are not complete but truncated on the screenshot so it is impossible to tell what was the exact request.

In summary: Make sure that you are using a way to make a request that actually shows the response headers and doesn't cache the response (because the Content-Type header is present in 200 OK response but not in 304 Not Modified which has no body so there is no Content-Type that would describe the body).